# Input string was not in a correct format when converting, insert values into the database inside the loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm making the string "*1234,5678,9101,1213,*" into an array so that I  can loop over this array and insert into the database column name "*CardID*" whose data type is *int*.

***Error Message:***

> Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a
>   correct format.

What strange is that the values from the loop get's inserted into the database table even though there is an error.

**File**: *CardsController.cs*

```
//1234,5678,9101,1213,
string[] CardNumbers = model.CardsNumbers.Split(',');
foreach (string CardNumber in CardNumbers)
{
    Card Card = new Card();
    Card.CardID = Convert.ToInt32(CardNumber); //Input string was not in a correct format.
    Card.TaxPayerTIN = model.TaxPayerTIN;
    Card.PortID = model.PortID;
    Card.AddedUserID = 1;
    Card.AddedDateTime = DateTime.Now;

    db.Cards.Add(Card);
    db.SaveChanges();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string "1234,5678,9101,1213," ends with the separator character (","), so the last element of the array returned by [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) will be the empty string. Passing an empty to string to [Convert.toInt32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx) is a format error.

You can avoid this behavior by specifying S[tringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
model.CardsNumbers.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

**RemoveEmptyEntries** - The return value does not include array elements that contain an empty string

Comment: You may also consider using `Int32.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`